# Equivalent statement for strtol in java

Tags: java, c

How can I write the below objecive C statement to java

```
unsigned char whole_byte;
char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
byte_chars[0] = ....;
byte_chars[1] = [....;
whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: Objective C is not the same as C. How have you compiled the `....;` in C?  Worse, how did you compile the `[....;` code?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Java that easily, because java is always pass-by-value and `String` objects are immutable. That means that it's not possible to pass a pointer as argument which will be filled with the string after the number by the method.

---

In your case, the question is just how to get the hexadecimal number on the beginning of a string. For this you can simply use `getLeadingInteger(string, 16)` with the first method below.

---

Here is the linear time solution:

```
public int getLeadingInteger(String inputString, int base) {
    char[] input = inputString.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    boolean positive = input[0] != '-';
    int start = input[0] == '+' || input[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0;
    int end = start;
    for(; end < input.length; end++) {
        try {
            // check if still a digit in right base
            Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(input[end]), base);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    int length = end - start;
    int result = Integer.parseInt(new String(input, start, length), base);
    return result * (positive ? 1 : -1);
}

public String getStringAfterInteger(String inputString, int base) {
    char[] input = inputString.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int start = input[0] == '+' || input[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0;
    int end = start;
    for(; end < input.length; end++) {
        try {
            // check if still a digit in right base
            Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(input[end]), base);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return inputString.substring(end, inputString.length());
        }
    }
    return ""; //if whole string is number
}
```

Both methods requires `inputString` to be at least of length 1 and and `getLeadingInteger()` reguires `inputString` to start with a valid number, since it is not clear, what number should be returned then.

---

This is a simpler solution that runs in `O(n^2)`:

```
public int getLeadingInteger(String input, int base) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++) {
        try {
            result = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, i), base);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public String getStringAfterInteger(String input, int base) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, i), base); //test if integer
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return input.substring(i-1, input.length());
        }
    }
    //if the whole string is a number, the part after the number is empty
    return "";
}
```

`input.length()` is required to be at least one in both cases.
Assuming that `Integer.parseInt()` works in linear time, both methods run in `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: It's quite easy in Java, and it has nothing to do with pass-by-value or the immutability of Strings.  The question is merely asking how to turn a hex string into a number.

Comment: @VGR, Doesn't `strtol` return the integer in the given base on the beginning of the string and write the no-longer-integer string after the starting number to the given pointer?

Comment: According to the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strtol.3.html), only the second argument is written to, which in the question is NULL.

Comment: @VGR updated it to linear time and answered question explicitly for base 16.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock, `String` is immutable in Java, but there are several alternatives that allow you to construct a `String` inside a method/function (like `StringBuffer` for example)  I have not downvoted you, but I think you have been well downvoted.

Comment: The key feature of `strtoX()` in C is that it parses a leading integer and then returns the location in the string of where the trailing stuff is.  Imagine parsing `-123kW', you get back an int with a value of `123` and a pointer to the `k` so you can continue processing.  With `Integer.parseInt()` you have to first split the String into two Strings `-123` and `kW`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the two characters in a variable.

```
char ch0 = 'A';
char ch1 = '9';
```

to convert to a number in hex you can do

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("" + ch0 + ch1, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all numeric types, including `byte`, are signed, so you'll want to parse the String as an int or short (though ints are much easier to work with in Java, generally):

```
// Important:  Java strings do not end with '\0', so your char array's
// length should be 2.
String s = String.valueOf(byte_chars);
byte whole_byte = (byte) Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is a simpler solution that runs in O(n^2):

This version is a classic implementation of C-styled strtol(), that tracks consumed input.  This version should run in O(n).

```
public final class Scan
{
    public int offset;
    public String str;

    public Scan(String str)
    {
        this(str, 0);
    }

    public Scan(String str, int off)
    {
        this.str = str;
        this.offset = off;
    }

    public static int strtol(String s, int radix)
    {
        return new Scan(s).strtol(radix);
    }

    public int strtol(int radix)
    {
        int next, value;

        if (str.length() <= offset || radix < 2 || 36 < radix)
            return 0;

        int sign = 0;
        switch (str.charAt(offset)) {
        case '-': sign = -1; offset++; break;
        case '+': sign = +1; offset++; break;
        }

        for (value = 0, next = offset; next < str.length(); next++) {
            int digit = Character.digit(str.charAt(next), radix);
            if (digit < 0) break;
            value *= radix;
            value += digit;
        }

        if (offset < next)
            offset = next;
        else if (sign != 0)
            offset--;

        return sign == 0 ? value : value * sign;
    }
}
```

The simple test example:

```
public final class x
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scan input = new Scan(args[0]);
        int value = input.strtol(10);
        System.out.println(value+" "+input.offset);
    }
}
```

So once compiled, you should get the following results:

```
$ java x ""
0 0
$ java x -
0 0
$ java x +
0 0
$ java x 1
1 1
$ java x +2
2 2
$ java x -3
-3 2
$ java x 123
123 3
$ java x +123
123 4
$ java x -123
-123 4
$ java x "7890, abc"
7890 4
$ java x "-7890, abc"
-7890 5
$
```